# How can I iterate through JSON arrays and show data in a table in React

Tags: json, reactjs

Here's my App.js file:

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import SongData from './songData';

     export default class App extends Component {

     render() {

      return(
        <div>
        {JSON.stringify(SongData)}
        </div>
      )
     }
   }
```

SongData is a variable that's defined in and exported from another file called songData:

```
   [{
    "active": 1,
    "createdAt": "2016-11-02T18:08:26.103Z",
    "difficulty": "Medium"
},
{
    "active": 0,
    "createdAt": "2013-10-02T18:08:26.103Z",
    "difficulty": "Difficult"
},
{
    "active": 1,
    "createdAt": "2015-12-02T18:08:26.103Z",
    "difficulty": "Easy"
}
]
```

What I want to do is in my App.js file iterate through all the JSON arrays and print out the active, createdAt, and difficulty of each song in a table.

I unsuccessfully tried a for loop and map, but niether worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your attempts, and we will help you solve the issues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SongData from './songData';

export default class App extends Component {

  songItems = () => {
    return SongData.map(s => {
      return <li>{s.active}</li>
    })
  }

  render() {

   return(
     <ul>
     {this.songItems()}
     </ul>
   )
  }
}
```

I'm making a method that's returning an array of List components, and then calling that method in the App's render method.

Comment: That looks like it should work, but the project won't compile after I tried it

Comment: SongData being an imported constant you could avoid the function and directly map on the array within the render method. Also, <li> elements should be wrapped in a <ul>.

Comment: This is the error I got: App.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__songData___default.a.map is not a function

Comment: @PierreKraemer you're totally right, I just pulled <li> as an example but it should be wrapped in a <ul>

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer does it work if SongData is defined directly in the same file? I did a quick test and it seems to be working for me. How are you exporting SongData?

Comment: One more comment: elements created by mapping an array should have a key prop defined. Ideally, if each element of the SongData array had a unique id, it could be used.

Comment: I have another file called songData.js which contains var SongData=[..]; and then exports.SongData = SongData; at the bottom

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer I think you should be able to do `export default [...]` in the SongData file and then `import songData from './songData` in your App, try that!

Comment: I did export default var SongData=[]; and got an error

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer try without var SongData, it's a default export so you don't need to name it. You should be able to just do `export default [...]`

Comment: Followup question: what if I wanted to sort the list on a button click?

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer I would then store the information in the state of the component and use an onClick to handle setting the state to the sorted array. See [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for how to implement.